# Receive and saving hex-values to arrays [STM32]

Tags: c, hex, qbytearray

I want receive and save hex values from PC to STM32-uC via UART.

Received HEX-Values looks like:

`FF00 4a85 04b5 08aa 6b7r 00FF`

(FF00 and 00FF are just checking bytes)

I want save lot of (different) rows of data that looks like:
`4a85 04b5 08aa 6b7r
4a85 04b5 08aa 6b7r
4a85 04b5 08aa 6b7r
4a85 04b5 08aa 6b7r
4a85 04b5 08aa 6b7r
4a85 04b5 08aa 6b7r
...................`

Later I have to read a memory and get int-values from every 2 Bytes:

04D1 -> 1233

1. Question:

I create multiarrays

```
volatile uint8_t testarrays[8][5000]; //data storage
```

and initialize with:

```
uint8_t received_str[12] //4 Bytes: `FF 00 and 00 FF` checksum
uint32_t h=0;
while(h<5000){
  if (receive_done_flag == TRUE) { //UART receive data
  testarrays[0][h]=received_str[2];
  testarrays[1][h]=received_str[3];
  testarrays[2][h]=received_str[4];
  testarrays[3][h]=received_str[5];
  testarrays[4][h]=received_str[6];
  testarrays[5][h]=received_str[7];
  testarrays[6][h]=received_str[8];
  testarrays[7][h]=received_str[9];
  }
  receive_done_flag == FALSE
  h++;
}
```

Is my idea right?

2. Question:

How can I read a data from storage later?
    uint16_t x=0;
    uint16_t y=0;
    uint8_t motorspeed_hex[8];

```
uint16_t speed_hex_M1;
uint16_t speed_hex_M2;
uint16_t speed_hex_M3;
uint16_t speed_hex_M4;

while(y<vert_length){
   x=0;
   while(x<hor_length){
   motorspeed_hex[x] = testarrays[x][y];
   x++;
   }
uint16_t speed_hex_M1 >> 8 = motorspeed_hex[0]
uint16_t speed_hex_M1 = motorspeed_hex[1]
uint16_t speed_hex_M2 >> 8  = motorspeed_hex[2]
uint16_t speed_hex_M2 = motorspeed_hex[3]
uint16_t speed_hex_M3 >> 8  = motorspeed_hex[4]
uint16_t speed_hex_M3 = motorspeed_hex[5]
uint16_t speed_hex_M4 >> 8  = motorspeed_hex[6]
uint16_t speed_hex_M4 = motorspeed_hex[7]
y++;
}
```

now, I have to convert speed_hex_M1.. to int-values, how can I do it in c?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I afraid you do not understand the basic things. you need to start from the c book, learn the language and datatypes, and then start programming microcontrollers. now it is too early for you

Comment: Thank you, but I try to learn it, by doing) What is wrong about datatypes?

Answer (score 0):

There are too many syntax errors to make sense on what you are trying to write. For example, in the first code fragment, you have "receive_done_flag == FALSE" that's a conditional expression producing 1 (true) or 0 (false), but the value of the conditional is not used. Do you mean to write an assignment statement? Or an if-statement? Or...?

In the second fragment, you have "speed_hex_M1 >> 8 = motorspeed_hex[0]". Again, nonsensical in C. The left side is the "variable (or storage unit)" that gets assigned to. So do you mean "motorspeed_hx[0] = speed_hex_M1 >> 8" or do you mean something else>

Answer (score 0):

About "receive_done_flag" - I,m using interrupt routine for UART. If the data is received the "receive_done_flag" will be set to TRUE, after data will be saved I set it to FALSE and waiting for new data via UART.

It was just idea/question, how can I  get a int values from hex? Example:

2 Bytes

```
uint16_t speed_hex_M1 = 04D1; 
uint16_t speed_hex_M2 = 04D1;
uint16_t speed_hex_M3 = 04D1;
uint16_t speed_hex_M4 = 04D1;
```

this is wrong, I know (right method below?):

```
uint16_t speed_hex_M1 >> 8 = motorspeed_hex[0]
uint16_t speed_hex_M1 = motorspeed_hex[1]
uint16_t speed_hex_M2 >> 8  = motorspeed_hex[2]
uint16_t speed_hex_M2 = motorspeed_hex[3]
uint16_t speed_hex_M3 >> 8  = motorspeed_hex[4]
uint16_t speed_hex_M3 = motorspeed_hex[5]
uint16_t speed_hex_M4 >> 8  = motorspeed_hex[6]
uint16_t speed_hex_M4 = motorspeed_hex[7]
```

so, 1 Byte

```
uint8_t motorspeed_hex[0] = 0x04;
uint8_t motorspeed_hex[1] = 0xD1;
....................
```

and then I can save it to multiple uint8_t arrays and later read it and convert hexadecimal values to decimal 04D1 -> 1233.

EDIT:

**motorspeed_hex[0] = motorspeed_hex[0] | ((speed_hex_M1 & 0xFF00) >> 8);
motorspeed_hex[1] = motorspeed_hex[1] | (speed_hex_M1 & 0x00FF);**